# Orion doesn't notify Cygnus

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I followed the official documentation about cygnus and orion. All generic enablers are deployed correctly, without errors in their log files. But something strange happens, Orion never notifies Cygnus.

To test this mechanism I followed the example with Car entity provided in the official documentation.

My entity creation bash script:

```
(curl $1:1026/v1/updateContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
  "contextElements": [
    {
      "type": "Car",
      "isPattern": "false",
      "id": "Car1",
      "attributes": [
      {
        "name": "speed",
        "type": "integer",
        "value": "75"
      },
      {
        "name": "fuel",
        "type": "float",
        "value": "12.5"
      }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "updateAction": "APPEND"
}
EOF
```

My entity subscription bash script:

```
(curl $1:1026/v1/subscribeContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Fiware-Service: vehicles' --header 'Fiware-ServicePath: /4wheels' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Car",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "Car1"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [
        "speed",
        "oil_level"
    ],
    "reference": "http://$2:5050/notify",
    "duration": "P1M",
    "notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONCHANGE",
            "condValues": [
                "speed"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "throttling": "PT1S"
}
EOF
```

My entity update bash script:

```
(curl $1:1026/v1/updateContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
  "contextElements": [
    {
      "type": "Car",
      "isPattern": "false",
      "id": "Car1",
      "attributes": [
      {
        "name": "speed",
        "type": "integer",
        "value": $2
      }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "updateAction": "UPDATE"
}
EOF
```

**Note**: Orion responds to all requests.

After executing these scripts, cygnus must receive reported information from orion and save it in the database, but nothing happens. 
Neither in /var/log/cygnus/cygnus.log file or in /var/log/contextBroker/contextBroker.log file are reported any information about orion notification.

**Note**: If I use the notify.sh script provided in the official documentation, Cygnus works well and saves all data in the database.

**Note**: I read in other questions problems about open ports but those don't apply to mine.

**EDIT 1**

After I subscribe the orion, the response is:

```
{
    "subscribeResponse": {
        "duration": "P1M",
        "subscriptionId": "563e12b4f4d8334d599753e0",
        "throttling": "PT1S"
    }
}
```

And when I update anentity, orion returns it:

```
{
    "contextResponses": [
        {
            "contextElement": {
                "attributes": [
                    {
                        "name": "speed",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "value": ""
                    }
                ],
                "id": "Car1",
                "isPattern": "false",
                "type": "Car"
            },
            "statusCode": {
                "code": "200",
                "reasonPhrase": "OK"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

To GET entity from orion I used the following script:

```
(curl $1:1026/v1/queryContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Car",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "Car1"
        }
    ]
} 
EOF
```

Response:

```
{
    "contextResponses": [
        {
            "contextElement": {
                "attributes": [
                    {
                        "name": "fuel",
                        "type": "float",
                        "value": "12.5"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "speed",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "value": "123"
                    }
                ],
                "id": "Car1",
                "isPattern": "false",
                "type": "Car"
            },
            "statusCode": {
                "code": "200",
                "reasonPhrase": "OK"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Note** The speed value was updated with success.

Comment: Which is the speed value before updating? You can check it with `GET /v1/contextEntities/Car1/attributes/speed`

Comment: It's updated. Orion works well but doesn't notify Cygnus.

Comment: Which value shows GET for speed? Which speed value do you use in the update request you send arter the GET? Thx!

Comment: In addition, note that you use `car1` and `car` in the subscription requets, but `Car1` and `Car` in the creation/update. Entity id and type are case sensitive.

Comment: The entity was incorrect so I fix it and I add more information about orion responses. @fgalan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account the `Fiware-Service` and `Fiware-ServicePath` headers in subscription request, it has been performeed in the "/4wheels" service path of the service "vehicles". However, entity creation request doesn't use such headers, so it is created in the default service path ("/") of the default service. Thus, the subscription is not "covering" the entity, so updates in the entity are not triggering notifications.

One solution to the problem would be to create the entity in the same service and service path of the subscription, i.e. "/4wheels" service path of the service "vehicles".

Please, check Orion official documentation about [service](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/user/multitenancy/index.html) and [service path](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/user/service_path/index.html) concepts.